# Identify applications with locks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In my environment there is a database Sybase ASE 15, that I need to replace with a Microsoft SQL Server 2000-r2.
Many users access this database via some applications, that sometimes "forget" to commit a transaction, then idle indefinitely keeping the table lock. This has a terrible effect: all other applications queue to obtain a lock on the tables affected, and are effectively stuck.
In Sybase I use a query that tells me which user is causing the problem; I can then either kill the task, or even go to him/her and find and correct the problem in the application.
This is the Sybase query:

```
select l.spid, SysLogin=s.name,SysObject=o.name, dbname
  from master..syslocks l, master..sysprocesses p, SIAM..sysobjects o, master..syslogins s
 where o.type='U'
   and p.spid=l.spid
   and l.id=o.id
   and p.suid=s.suid
```

The output produced looks like this:

```
81  john    authors     maindb
88  mary    authors     maindb
88  mary    books       maindb
```

Unfortunately, syslocks does not exist in Mssql, at least not in the version I am using.
How do I convert the query to work on Mssql?
Of course, if there is an alternative way of achieving the same result that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get it to work using only system procedure [sp_lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187749%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Although it's deprecated and it will be removed in a future version, it still works on SQL 2008 R2 and SQL 2012.

```
USE master;
GO
EXEC sp_lock;
GO
EXEC sp_lock 53; -- 53 is the spid for some specific user session;
GO
```

Another way is to use the DMV [sys.dm_tran_locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
Select *
from sys.dm_tran_locks dl
join sys.sysprocesses sp on dl.request_session_id = sp.spid
```

I think that a more clearer way is to use Adam Machanic's procedure [WhoIsActive](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2011/04/06/who-is-active-options-a-month-of-monitoring-part-6-of-30.aspx) which has a specific parameter for showing locks for a session.

Use them all and choose whatever suits you best, but the WhoIsActive procedure provides more info than just locks.

Comment: The second one is my favorite

Comment: @carlo.borreo Don't forget to try the WhoIsActive procedure, it will show you some nice info (including wait stats).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for transactions that have been left open. Try "DBCC OPENTRAN('db_name') WITH TABLERESULTS, NO_INFOMSGS" to get the currently open transactions, including when they were started. That would be a good starting point. There are probably some fancier DMV's you could use - but DBCC OPENTRAN works across a whole bunch of different versions (SQL Server 2000+).

Answer (score 1):

Take 2, the newer DMV based solution.

`SELECT des.session_id, 
OBJECT_NAME(resource_associated_entity_id) [Entity],
des.login_name,
db_name(der.database_id) [database]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests der
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions des ON des.session_id = der.session_id
JOIN sys.dm_tran_locks dtl ON des.session_id = request_session_id
WHERE command NOT IN ('BACKUP LOG', 'BACKUP DATABASE', 'DBCC') AND
resource_type <> 'DATABASE' AND
open_transaction_count > 0 AND 
start_time > dateadd(minute, -2, getdate())`

Lists the data you want for open transactions that have current locks. There is a whole bunch more information you can get out of it, but this is close to what you get in SYBASE. I've excluded non-DML commands and database locks (of which you'll get one per connection).

Comment: *sigh* please post ONE answer. Is there any reason your two answers couldn't be combined just like Marian combined his?